# Borde-Guth-Vilenkin (BGV) Theorem equation for the motion free falling observer

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, observers, geodesics

In the derivation of the BGV theorem paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.10958

There is the following relation (numbered (8)):

$\dfrac{d}{d s}\left[a^2(t) \dfrac{d \mathbf{x}}{d s}\right]=0$

It's very likely dumb but i don't see how they get that start from the FLWR metric and geodesic equation...

If anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be seen from the variational principle
$$
\delta \int\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}=0
$$
and eq.(7) in the paper, i.e. $u_\mu u^\mu=-1$. From the Lagrange equations
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x_\mu}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_\mu},
$$
where the dot means derivative with respect to $s$, it is seen immediately that
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot x_0^2-a^2(t)|\dot{\bf x}|^2}}a^2(t)\dot{\bf x}\right)=0,
$$
giving the expected result.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to fill-in the gaps in the next three weeks and understand why you have a square root in th LHS of the final result that doesn't appear on the paper. I will come back after these 3 weeks if i fail.

Comment: But the square root is 1 due to $u_\mu u^\mu=-1$ so, it is exactly the result in the paper.

Comment: Indeed the square root is 1. Try however to give me the time to check all LoL.... You are faster than your shadow and i'm slow as a snail... ;-)